# Is it possible to pick next row's cell value on same column if condition not matched?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table `flaggedcomment` and a table `price`.

In `flaggedcomment`, there are two empty columns `Price_DateTime` and `Price_Open` which I want to copy from `price`, depending on the `ON` conditions. Query as below.

```
UPDATE flaggedcomment as t1 
        LEFT JOIN price as t2 
             ON t1.Ticker_Ticker_ID = t2.Ticker_Ticker_ID AND t1.Comment_DateTime = t2.Price_DateTime
SET t1.Price_DateTime = t2.Price_DateTime, t1.Price_Open = t2.Price_Open
```

This query will leave some cells with null value because there's no match between `t1.Comment_DateTime` and `t2.Price_DateTime`.

Is there a way to "pick" the next available `Price_DateTime` if there's no match found?

For example, if the value of `t1.Comment_DateTime` is `2014-09-29 20:44:00` but it's not exist in `t2.Price_DateTime`, can I pick the next row's `Price_DateTime` value, e.g. `2014-09-30 08:00:00`?

I am new to deal with MySQL queries and I've tried my best in explaining what I want to do. If I didn't explain my question well, please let me know and I will try to explain it further.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a small table of sample data and expected results?

Comment: @McAdam331 Hi, sure. I will update my question, please bear with me. Thank you. :)

Comment: Based on your edit, it might be more helpful to see a few lines from the original two tables, so other users can understand how those two tables would relate into the final one. I would browse some other SQL questions for how to format the table. If not, creating an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) would allow other users to recreate your issue and try to solve the problem.

Comment: You can perform another query, put a sub-query in your query, or change your tables to show what's in the next row. I'd use a subquery.

Comment: @McAdam331 okay, I will improve my question.